# python-tarantool call parameters

Tags: python, call, tarantool

I want to call box.space.auth_user:auto_increment{"8", 7, 7, 7} from python script.
This is what I do in python

```
import tarantool
connection = tarantool.connect('127.0.0.1', 3303)
connection.call('box.space.auth_user:auto_increment', ("8", 7, 7, 7))
```

And then I get the error:

```
[string "-- schema.lua (internal file)..."]:921: bad argument #1 to 'insert' (table expected, got string)
```

This is how I define my **auth_user** schema

```
box.schema.space.create('auth_user',{if_not_exists=true})
box.space.auth_user:create_index('primary', {type='TREE', if_not_exists=true, unique=true, parts={1,'NUM'}})
box.space.auth_user:create_index('login', {type='HASH', if_not_exists=true, unique=true, parts={2,'STR'}})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug, please use `[["8", 7, 7, 7]]` or `(("8", 7, 7, 7), )`.

```
In [4]: connection.call('box.space.auth_user:auto_increment', [["8", 7, 7, 7]])
Out[4]:
- [1, '8', 7, 7, 7]
```

tarantool-python uses array to show that it's arguments, so it was analog for `box.space.auth_user:auto_increment("8", 7, 7, 7)`, not `{}`